# How can I put a % after %1$d in sprintf?

Tags: php, printf

I have this sprintf based string:

```
<?php echo sprintf( 'Over %1$d (warning) and %2$d (bad) are recorded', 75, 90 ); ?>
```

It outputs:

`Over 75 (warning) and 90 (bad) are recorded`

How can I make this string be:

`Over 75% (warning) and 90% (bad) are recorded`

I thought I could use:

```
<?php echo sprintf( 'Memory over %1$d% (warning) and %2$d% (bad) are recorded', 75, 90 ); ?>
```

But the % on the end of `%1$d%` and `%2$d%` interfere with the sprintf function and result in:

`Memory over 75warning) and 90bad) are recorded`

Comment: Use `%%` to print a literal `%`.

Comment: FYI, the [PHP manual page for `sprintf`](https://www.php.net/sprintf) also covers this in its list of "specifiers".

Comment: `<?php echo sprintf( 'Over %1$d (warning) and %2$d%% (bad) are recorded', 75, 90 );`